# Changing Launcher Size on Cinnamon on Ubuntu 20.4

Tags: launcher

I'm new to Ubuntu and Cinnamon. I created a series of Launchers to launch chromium with links to my various streaming services. It all works fine but the Launcher is small on high resolution.

The only setting I can find in desktop and allows to set icon size to large or larger but this is not large enough. I can't find in the config files that setting.

The other advice to just right clicking and change the size is on a older version and will not work on Ubuntu 20.

I just looking for a launcher that I adjust the size.

Just a side note. The digital photo applet included with Ubuntu cinnamon would be ideal if it could launch a command on click.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 20 or 20.4 do you mean 20.04?